# Unable to get exif data of image stored in server using PIL

Tags: python, odoo, python-imaging-library

I am working with a method that returns me the base64 of a image file stored in the server. Here's how it returns me the data:

```
r = open(full_path,'rb').read().encode('base64')
return r
```

What I am trying to achieve with that return data is to get the exif data of the image file stored. Here is how I am doing this

```
image_string = StringIO(base64.b64decode(r))
image = Image.open(image_string)
exif = dict(image._getexif().items())
...
```

I have used the same code earlier for the same purpose, But at that time I was getting image data from the database. This time I am trying the same thing using file stored data, it is showing the following error:

```
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'" while evaluating
```

Also tried to accomplish this by using:

```
image_string = StringIO(r.decode('base64'))
```

But it also didn't work. Any hints what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Here is the print of image variable 
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1632x1224 at 0x7F957995C650>

Comment: Can you please confirm that the image has valid exif data? i.e. that you used other software on this specific image which provides valid exif data?

Comment: I have tried using different images, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code it worked for you and it is working for me. The error is coming wether because your images does not contain valid exif data or because of the _getexif() method itself as it still experimental

Comment: But confusingly this _getexif is working when I get the data of image saved in database but not when I get the same from reading file.